# Am I able to retrieve a JIRA HTTP URL using a GET Request when I use CORS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, cors, jira

I am currently trying to retrieve information from a URL of a JIRA Issue using an MVC application coded in Visual Basic.  I am calling the URL by using a GET request in AJAX.

The URL is successfully returning the correct information in POSTMAN. But when I try to use CORS to allow my local host using the following headers in my web.config:

```
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Tpye, Accept"/>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:XXXXX"/>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT" />
```

I am still getting the following error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  Origin 'http://localhost:XXXXX' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Even though I have added the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the Web.config.

I was wondering is it actually possible to return the information in this way or am I doing this correctly.  If it is possible but you need more information on the GET request or anything else I will add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the JIRA system that I was trying to pull information was not hosted online so that was the reason why I was not able to retrieve information and it was giving me the error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:XXXXX' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.